# Conditional Format if Column in Another Worksheet Contains Date Older than 30 Days

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to Conditional Format a cell in Worksheet A if any date in a column of cells (other than blank cells) in Worksheet B is older than 30 days. Can anyone help?

I've figured this out for conditionally formatting when a single cell is older than 30 days, but not if any one among a column of cells (other than blank cell) is older than 30 days.

The idea is to have something light up on Worksheet A, if a cell on Worksheet B is stale.

Answer (score 0):

Please select the desired cell and try a Conditional Formatting formula rule of the following kind:

```
=COUNTIF('Worksheet B'!A:A,"<"&TODAY()-30)
```

with formatting of your choice.